# SDB Connection with my Samsung smart TV showing connecting status for so long

Tags: cmd, connection, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am using Smart Development Bridge (SDB) to connect Samsung Tizen TV from my PC, using command as

`sdb connect <ip> <port>`

its is showing ->

`Connecting to 'ip:port'...` for so long

Have any suggestion or solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

SDB(Smart Development Bridge) connections are network IP-based, meaning that they rely on your internet connection speed. If your connection is slow or unreliable, you may experience slower than usual SDB connections.

To improve your connection speed, we recommend using a wired network connection instead of wireless one. This can help reduce latency and improve the stability of your connecdtion.

Another tip is to wait a sufficient amout of time after the Tizen boot before connecting to SDB. This can help ensure that all necessary services and processes have fully started up, which can improve the speed and reliability of your SDB connection.